# Clear product description formatting and styles opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

Im trying to do something with my opencart store, which contains more than 8000 products with their descriptions! The question is ... I started work on this opencart store after the products were already inserted, but the descriptions was with wrong formatting like colored text, used unwanted fonts and font-styles etc. i have a very basic knowledge about opencart developing and php coding and MVC framework, BUT i want to clear the formatting on every description, and just leave the font-weight: bold; (because i want to save the copywriters work till now). 
Does anybody have idea, how can i do it? I tried to export the database, edit with excel, edit the mysql database, tryed regular expressions and i still dont find the right decision!
Thanks all!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use **Export/Import Tool** https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=17 to export > edit > import products.

Comment: I cannot use this tool unfortunately, because i get an error like :" Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in ..." which i cannot resolve...

Comment: Temporarily use `memory_limit = 1024M` to export & import. When you finish set `memory_limit = 128M` as it was.

Comment: If you are still getting **Fatal errors**, you should export products by `By id range`. For example, export from 0-1000, 1001-2000 ... 7001-8000.

Comment: Yes, thank you! By id range works for me! But the problem now is with cleaning the description...

Comment: Maybe this https://trumpexcel.com/filter-bold-font-formatting-in-excel/ guide can help you filter the cells with `font-weight: bold;` and clear formatting in all other cells.

Comment: Thanks for this its very usefull! But when i export the descriptions, they are appearing like unformatted text so im not seeing the bold text (for example) im seeing just font-style: bold;
Its just a text cell and thats why its so hard to select all the cells with style formatting (because its html)